# How to associate OpenTelemetry trace/span ID to Google Cloud Logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, open-telemetry, google-cloud-logging

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/trace-log-integration):

To associate a log entry with a trace by setting the trace field in the LogEntry object. The trace field must be set to a string with the following format:

> ```
> projects/PROJECT_ID/traces/TRACE_ID where PROJECT_ID is your Google
> ```
>
> Cloud project ID and TRACE_ID is the trace identifier
>
> To associate a log entry with a span when using the Cloud Logging API,
> set the spanId field in the LogEntry object to the 16-character
> hexadecimal encoding of the span's ID. For example, to associate a log
> entry with a span that has an ID of 74, set the span ID to
> `000000000000004a`.

However, this assumes that I am using [`@google-cloud/trace-agent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/trace-agent), which I am not – I am using [open-telemetry](/questions/tagged/open-telemetry).

Is there a way to associate logs with Open Telemetry by assigning them meta data that Google would recognize or must I submit all the logs directly to OpenTelemetry collector?

Comment: Context: are you using the OTEL collector with googlecloudexporter to export logs? If so, the otel collector needs the `spanId` and `traceId` to be set in the payload that is sent, the googlecloudexporter will automatically create the `trace` field.

If not, you will need to manually set the `trace` and `spanId` fields in your structured logs.

Comment: @gajus did you got any resolution for this. I am struggling with the same issue. We have an angular app i am testing locally(localhost), not sure how to send these logs to gcp log explorer. (in azure app insight we can do this by writing app insight connecting string)